# How to add class to the options for type radio present under radios?

Tags: views, 8, forms

```
function template_preprocess_bef_radios(&$variables) {
  $variables['children'] = Element::children($variables['element']);
  _bef_preprocess_nested_elements($variables);
    foreach($variables['element'] as $tid => $value) {
        if (is_numeric($tid) || $tid === 'All') {
            $value['#attributes']['class'][] = Html::cleanCssIdentifier($value['#title']);
        }
    }
 }
```

While trying the above does not add class to radio button under radios(which has multiple options)
How can I add class to the options ?

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there just you should change `$variables['element'][$tid]['#attributes']['class']` instead of `$value['#attributes']['class']` try with:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function template_preprocess_bef_radios(&$variables) {
  // No need to this two lines 
//  $variables['children'] = Element::children($variables['element']);
//  _bef_preprocess_nested_elements($variables);
  foreach($variables['element'] as $tid => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($tid) || $tid === 'All') {
      $variables['element'][$tid]['#attributes']['class'][] = Html::cleanCssIdentifier($value['#title']);
    }
  }
}
```